# How to get the last drawn point for a Geometry in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I wonder if I can get the position of the last point for a geometry in OpenLayers?

For example, I have an `OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString`, how to get its last point?

***Clarification in the comments:***
In fact, what I want is the last drawed point for the polygon. Is it impossible?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString.getVertices it will give you the starting & ending points.

Comment: Then how about the polygon? It seems that the `getVertices` only works for `LineString`.

Comment: I can't imagine what a 'last point' would mean when it comes to a polygon. What about when the Polygon has holes, or the polygon is a multi-part feature?

Comment: Additionally, Polygons inherit from OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection, which have a `getVertices` method.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: I have tried the `getVertices` method of `Polygon` while, it always return the  empty array.

Comment: If you do `geometry.getVertices(false)` you get an array of all vertices. If you want just the end points, you won't get anything, because end points don't make sense when you are talking about a polygon.

Comment: In fact, what I want is the last drawed point for the polygon. Is is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to get the last point which was drawn, using the drawFeature control.

However, you could have a look at the code, and make your own custom drawFeature control, which does this. The drawFeature control is based on [OpenLayers.Handler](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler-js.html%E2%80%8E), which does the heavy lifting in the background. You could easily listen to the events and get the last click.